# My domain link is flagged as dangerous/spam in emails

Tags: domains, email, spam

Recently my website was hacked and there were many redirects to other sites that were setup. I have cleaned up everything and the issues were fixed. Google initially flagged it was insecure and was showing warning when anyone clicks from google search, which was resolved by submitting a request to them. Now any emails that contain any links to my site is going to spam for many users and gmail displays a red warning message like "This message seems dangerous" "It contains a suspicious link that is used to steal people's personal information"

How can this be resolved as many important emails are now going to SPAM and/or being flagged.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to make sure everything is right at your end first.

  - This may help [from Webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9157/gmail-treats-mails-from-my-domain-as-spam-why-how-to-avoid-it).
  - Also read this [from Google](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=81126)
- Then find out which ISPs are flagging your emails.
- Finally contact them one at a time and make a request.